# How to delete a file with string.numbers.string format by passing a command in Airflow

Tags: shell, unix, airflow

This is the file format I have `ABD.123244.trig` , when I try to remove the file in the terminal I used `rm -f ABD.+([0-9]).trig`, but when I use the same thru Airflow scheduler, it throws`error unexpected token '('`

please help

This command `rm -f ABD.+([0-9]).trig` doesn't work while passing it thru Airflow scheduler. it throws `error unexpected token '('`

Comment: Have you enabled the `extglob` option in the airflow invironment?

Answer (score 0):

Airflow bash operator runs the bash command with:

```bash
bash -c "<your bash command>"
```

To use an extended globbing pattern in `bash`, you have to enable the `extglob` shell option. You can try:

```py
BashOperator(task_id="bash_task", bash_command="shopt -s extglob\n rm -f ABD.+([0-9]).trig")
```

Answer (score 0):

The `+` is not a special character in bash, therefore, your expression `+(...)` does not make any sense. Neither does `.+`.

You are thinking regular expressions instead of gobbing patterns.

Try this:

```
echo ABD.[0-9]*
```

and the whole command would be:

```
rm -f ABD.[0-9]*.trig
```

Comment: also, you can not use () in bash for referring to filenames without quoting or escaping, because () are special to bash syntax and mean different things depending on context. if a file name is literally: `MyPictrures (2022)`, then in bash you must refer to it as e.g. `"MyPictrures (2022)"` or `MyPictrures \(2022\)`